# user.routing.yml -- What is the significance of "_entity_form: user_role.default"?

Tags: 8, routes

In [user.routing.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.routing.yml/8.2.x), I'm not able to understand the line 83.

```
user.role_add:
  path: '/admin/people/roles/add'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: user_role.default
    _title: 'Add role'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer permissions'
```

What does _entity_form: user_role.default mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, it means that route shows an entity form to edit the user role entity; in particular, it shows its default form.

In details, `user_role` is the ID for the [`Role`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21Role.php/class/Role/8.2.x) class, which implements the user role entity.

```
@ConfigEntityType(
  id = "user_role",
  label = @Translation("Role"),
  handlers = {
    "storage" = "Drupal\user\RoleStorage",
    "access" = "Drupal\user\RoleAccessControlHandler",
    "list_builder" = "Drupal\user\RoleListBuilder",
    "form" = {
      "default" = "Drupal\user\RoleForm",
      "delete" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDeleteForm"
    }
  },
  admin_permission = "administer permissions",
  config_prefix = "role",
  static_cache = TRUE,
  entity_keys = {
    "id" = "id",
    "weight" = "weight",
    "label" = "label"
  },
  links = {
    "delete-form" = "/admin/people/roles/manage/{user_role}/delete",
    "edit-form" = "/admin/people/roles/manage/{user_role}",
    "edit-permissions-form" = "/admin/people/permissions/{user_role}",
    "collection" = "/admin/people/roles",
  },
  config_export = {
    "id",
    "label",
    "weight",
    "is_admin",
    "permissions",
  }
)
```

`user_role.default` is referring to the default form the annotation for that class describes.

```
"form" = {
  "default" = "Drupal\user\RoleForm",
  "delete" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDeleteForm"
}
```

In this case, it's the form implemented from the [`RoleForm`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21RoleForm.php/class/RoleForm/8.2.x) class.

When you see `_entity_form` in a route, it always mean the route is showing a form implemented from an entity.